# override multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

how can i get variable in class which is override multiprocessing in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import os

class TestMultiprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.myvar = ''

    def myfunc(self):
        return os.getpid() 

    def run(self):
        self.myvar = self.myfunc()

mlist = []
for i in range(10):
    t = TestMultiprocess()
    mlist.append(t)
    t.start()

for j in mlist:
    t.join()
    print t.myvar
```

i can not get value "myvar" from class TestMultiprocess, i just get blank. But i already override the run() function from Process.

sorry if my spell very bad ...

Answer (score 3):

The run() will executed in a separate process; processes don't share memory, normally. multiprocessing does support shared variables, though, through the explicit [Value](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import os

class TestMultiprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.myvar = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)

    def myfunc(self):
        return os.getpid()

    def run(self):
        self.myvar.value = self.myfunc()

mlist = []
for i in range(10):
    t = TestMultiprocess()
    mlist.append(t)
    t.start()

for j in mlist:
    j.join()
    print j.myvar.value
```

Comment: i see now.. But if i use Value or Array how long byte that i can save with that shared variable? because i try it with reponse from urllib2 i get error "too long string"...

Comment: You can't store variable-sized stuff in shared memory. The shared memory gets a fixed size, you have to use exactly as much memory as you originally allocated. To exchange strings between processes, I recommend to use the Queue interface (which will be a different programming model).

Answer (score 0):

replace t with j in the last loop

```
for j in mlist:
    j.join()     # t with j
    print j.myvar  # t with j
```

**EDIT**: and this will not solve your problem

by the way if you want to get the process pid you don't have to override the run() method just for that you can just do:

```
for j in mlist:
    j.pid
```