# How to subclass a synchronized Queue with extra parameters

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to subclass [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and the following code throws an exception:

```
from Queue import Queue

class MyQueue(Queue, object):
    def __init__(self, my_stuff = None):
        super(MyQueue, self).__init__()
        self.my_stuff = my_stuff

    def my_function(self):
        return self.my_stuff
```

And I'm calling it from `__main__` like so:

```
a_queue = MyQueue(my_stuff = "some stuff")
print a_queue
```

I am getting, as expected:

```
$ ./my_queue.py
some stuff
```

But I only get that if I also inherit from `object` (per [new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class)). Otherwise I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./my_queue", line 13, in <module>
  a_queue = MyQueue(my_stuff = "some stuff")
File "./my_queue", line 6, in __init__
  super(MyQueue, self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Why? It apparently doesn't work for Queue as easily as it does for e.g. mp.Process (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711140/python-subclassing-process-with-parameter) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Queue class does not support the [super](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#super) feature since it is an old style class.
This way inheriting from object will solve your problem (make it a new style class).
But if you want to avoid it just call init directly

change it to:

```
from  Queue import Queue

class MyQueue(Queue):
     def __init__(self, my_stuff = None):
         Queue.__init__(self)
         self.my_stuff = my_stuff

     def my_function(self):
         return self.my_stuff
```

while old classes in python cannot do this New style classes may use `super(Foo, self)` where Foo is the class and self is the instance.

```
super(type[, object-or-type])
```

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that
>   used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

The [new style class](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) is usually a better choice

Comment: Thanks, Omer. Please update the URLs in your answer to Python 2.7 and not Python 3.x, since I tagged the question with this version of Python.

Comment: thanks, done.
if this answer solved your problem can you accept it?